# How to deploy django app with channels and websocket on cpanel?

Tags: django, cpanel, wsgi, asgi

i have a django with websocket and channels wokring locally using daphne and i want to deploy it to cpanel ?

I try to use : a2wsgi but it didn't work

i want to know if cpanel works with asgi application?
and if there is another way to deploy it with cpanel